# Definition of traits in a separate file

Tags: module, rust, traits

I define two structs

```rust
pub struct Rect {
    pub width:  f32,
    pub length: f32
}

//and

pub struct Circle {
    pub radius:  f32
}
```

Then I define a trait `Area` and I implement this trait for both `Circle` and `Rect`. Everything works fine when I put all source code in a single `main.rs` file.

Now I want to organize my source code. In particular, I want to create a folder `/src/geometry`, create three `rs` files under that folder:

```rust
// /src/geometry/rect.rs
pub struct Rect {
    pub width:  f32,
    pub length: f32
}
```

```rust
// /src/geometry/circle.rs
pub struct Circle {
    pub radius:  f32
}
```

and

```rust
// /src/geometry/traits.rs
pub trait Area {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}
```

And finally I want to use these structs from `main.rs`.

I spent a couple of days, read through all examples I found on the Internet, but I still can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**:
Project structure:

```
src
  geometry
     rect.rs 
     circle.rs
     traits.rs
  geometry.rs
  main.rs
```

```rust
// rect.rs

pub struct Rect {
    pub width:  f32,
    pub length: f32
}

impl Area for Rect {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.width * self.length
    }
}

impl Perimeter for Rect {
    fn perimeter(&self) -> f32 {
        2.0*(self.width + self.length)
    }
}
```

```rust
// circle.rs

pub struct Circle {
    pub radius:  f32
}

impl Area for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        3.14*self.radius*self.radius
    }
}

impl Perimeter for Circle {
    fn perimeter(&self) -> f32 {
        2.0*3.14*self.radius
    }
}
```

```rust
// traits.rs

pub trait Perimeter {
    fn perimeter(&self) -> f32;
}

pub trait Area {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}
```

```rust
// geometry.rs
pub mod rect;
pub mod circle;
```

```rust
// main.rs

mod geometry;
use geometry::rect::Rect;
use geometry::circle::Circle;

fn main() {
     let rect = Rect{ width: 1.0, length: 2.0 };
     let circle = Circle{ radius: 2.3 };

     println!("{}", rect.area());
     println!("{}", circle.area());
}
```

COMPILER ERROR MSGS

```
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Area` in this scope
 --> src/geometry/rect.rs:6:6
  |
6 | impl Area for Rect {
  |      ^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Perimeter` in this scope
  --> src/geometry/rect.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl Perimeter for Rect {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Area` in this scope
 --> src/geometry/circle.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl Area for Circle {
  |      ^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Perimeter` in this scope
  --> src/geometry/circle.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl Perimeter for Circle {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error: aborting due to 4 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0405`.
error: could not compile `chapter10`.
```

Comment: What precisely does "not working" look like here? What compiler errors show up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, in `circle.rs` and `rect.rs` you need to add `use crate::geometry::traits::{Area, Perimeter};`: this takes care of the errors you pasted.

Then, in `main.rs` you need to `use geometry::traits::Area;` otherwise you can't call `.area()` method. In order to do that, you need to make the `traits` module public in `geometry.rs`: `pub mod traits;` (or at least public within the crate: `pub(crate) mod traits;`).

Personally, I would also rename `geometry.rs` to `geometry/mod.rs`.

Comment: Is `mod.rs` a kinda widely accepted standard among Rust developers? It is widely used in Rust source code as I've noticed.

Comment: @HardFork `foo/mod.rs` is an alternative way of placing `foo.rs` and has the same meaning. The explicit directory makes it somewhat easier to create further submodules, but otherwise it's a matter of taste.